# No visible @interface for NSDictionary in command-line utility

Tags: objective-c, command-line, nsdictionary

Alright, I'll keep this simple. I am trying to write an `array` of `dictionaries` into a command-line program that will generate a `plist` I need for an app I'm writing.

Problem is, the program doesn't like the fact that there isn't an `@interface` section, which baffles me, but then again, I'm new to `Objective-C`, and am just in the process of finding my feet. There are many things that can be done in this language and many errors which get past me still. Keep that in mind when you're answering - what's obvious to you won't be necessarily obvious to me.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // Add first dictionary below:
        // 1:
        NSDictionary *Dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"Back-2.png" forKey:@"ImageName"];
       [Dict1 setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:@"HidePair1"];
       [Dict1 setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:@"HidePair2"];
       [Dict1 setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey:@"HidePair3"];
       [Dict1 setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey:@"HidePair4"];
       [Dict1 setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey:@"HidePair5"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"Mass (kg)" forKey: @"Label1"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"Velocity (m/s)" forKey: @"Label2"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"null" forKey: @"Label3"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"null" forKey: @"Label4"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"null" forKey: @"Label5"];
       [Dict1 setObject: @"kg • m/s" forKey: @"Units"];
       [dictionaryArray addObject: Dict1];
    }
}
```

I was prescribed this code on the Apple Dev forums, so this isn't something I've cooked up and I assumed it was generally correct (here come lectures about assumptions), so something tells me there is an issue elsewhere with the code that I'm not seeing.

The `NSArray` called `dictionaryArray` is declared and there is not an error with it. It is in a single line right above the double comment.

Here's the error, *verbatim*:

```
'No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'setObject: forKey:''
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **`NSMutableDictionary`** instead of **`NSDictionary`**. You can't set object in `NSDictionary`. You can add object in **`NSDictionary`** only in initialization of **`NSDictionary`** object.

Comment: I realized this right after posting, and immediately called myself a string of expletives. Still, good call though.